# SubscriptionSchedulerCmd not running without a registered userId - HCL Commerce / IBM WCS

Tags: websphere-commerce

I am implementing the OOB Recurring Order feature in our store.
I am setting up the SubscriptionSchedulerCmd as explained in this wiki https://help.hcltechsw.com/commerce/9.0.0/admin/tasks/tin_settingupscheduler.html?hl=setting%2Cup%2Cscheduler%2Cprocess%2Csubscriptions%2Crecurring%2Corders

But the scheduler is not running as expected. I see the following error from the logs
CommerceSrvr  A AccManager performForUserAuthorizationCheck(AccCommand) The run-as-identity must be of registered type.
ExtendedInfo  I   CWXFR9010I: Extended information : [context=com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext : [bInitialize = false][bRecalibrate = true][inCallerId = -1000][inRunAsId = 291003][inStoreId = 10151][istrChannelId = null][bDirty = true][bRequestStarted = true][iOriginalSerializedString = 0&-1000&-1000&null][iToken = 21450482:true:true:0]] [queryString=] [schedulerName=SubscriptionSchedulerCmd]

But it runs fine for the recurring orders of one particular user if I give that userIdin the associated user field in the schduler configurator. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SubscriptionSchedulerCmd only runs for USERS of REGISTERTYPE = "R". So if a USER is both R and S the precedence is for S for the command will not run and will not create child orders.